# iWork'09 retail installation DVD : does the language and/or region matter?

Tags: install, iwork, language, dvd

**Does iWork'09 retail DVD allow installation in any language or shall one care about it?**

- Example: Can on install iWork in German from a DVD purchased in the
  US?

**Is iWork'09 retail DVD the same worldwide, or is it region-specific or country-specific?**

- Example: Can a European user install iWork from a DVD that was
  initially commercialized on another continent.
- Example: Can a user in Belgium use a DVD that was initially commercialized in France?

Comment: If you have the dvd, can you test?

Comment: What Mac, what OS? The iWork apps have been free to download from the Apple Store since 2013.

Comment: @Solar Mike: I cannot test yet ; it is pre-purchase question.

Comment: @Tetsujin: MacBook Air A1466, mid-2012 running OS X 10.14 Mojave. The iWork apps are still listed buy can no longer be installed from the App Store as an error popup requires Mac OS 11. However, it seems that iWork'09 could still be installed as Mojave supports 32-bit apps, and then possibly upgraded through the App Store.

Comment: IWork '09 needs 10.4.11 or 10.5.6 or later, so it should install on your 10.14 Mojave.

Comment: You night struggle - if they will install, then they won't update at all, because the newest version won't run on Mojave… [tbh, I'm surprised they weren't on the Mac from new].

Comment: Regarding Mohave, see  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8565526

Comment: @Tetsujin: From what I read, it would upgrade not to the newest version, but to the most recent compatible version. (i.e. the upgrade would reach older versions than the lastest ones visible in the App store). Once installed, iWork 9.0 could also be updated to 9.3. This update is a priori still available. I think it is worth attempting.

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: Thanks. I had read it. But some other infos still let me hope.

Answer (score 1):

iWork is multilingual and the same everywhere, but whether the very ancient 09 version can be installed and used on your machine is a different question.

iWork apps have been free to download from the app store for many years now, so it's not obvious what use one of the old dvd's would be to anyone.  I don't know whether docs produced by iWork 09 can even be read correctly by the current iWork, since Apple has [changed formats](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/IWork) a couple times.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know. I had done of internet search for compatibility before asking and it seems that the only possible way to get iWork on my machine is installing iWork'09 and then upgrading it (or letting it so). For details, see my answer to Tetsujin in the comments of my question. Not absolutely sure that it will work, but worth trying.

Comment: Is there a special reason you need iWork?  The free LibreOffice is more compatible with MS Office and has the same features as the latter for the most part.  There are a number of other word processors better than Pages.

Comment: Yes. My customer is asking it, because working with other people that themselves are using iWork.